# NetBeans perpetually "running..." and will not compile

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

This is my Java code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Objects {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It does not compile when I try to run the file (it simply sits there with "running..." forever). When I remove the final line, it does compile.

Any thoughts?

I am attempting to follow the lesson below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT-J-0nGyzU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did in fact successfully compile. The reason it say "running ..." is because when you call `setVisible(true)` your window becomes visible, and the program keeps running until it's closed.

It sounds like you couldn't see the window, even though the window you created became "visible".

Try adding

```
// Set the size of the window.
window.setSize(600, 400);

// Position the window in the middle of the screen.
window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

// End the application when X is pressed.
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

before calling `setVisible(true)`. This should ensure you can see the window you created.